# Convert array of JavaScript object property value to an int

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the cleanest way of converting an array of JavaScript property values to an int? (Would like all `a` properties to be an int)

```
var myArray = [
    {
       a: "12",
       b: "hits"
    },
    {
       a: "16",
       b: "hits"
    }
]
```

Comment: quite strange question, you can traverse all properties and call for each parseInt.

Comment: You want to convert an array of objects to a single int? How? Sum them? Or you want to just convert the `a` property (because I have no idea what you'd expect to do with the `b` property of `"hits"`)

Comment: Does nobody read anymore, it clearly states *"all `a` properties to an int using parseInt"*

Comment: Sorry I want all the a properties to be an int.  parseInt is fine.  I was hoping to use map to achieve this.

Comment: @KingKongFrog: Okay, you could probably do it with `map`, or you could just use a regular loop. What problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: I know how to loop, wasn't sure how to use map in this case.  But the answer below helps now :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0f3x1oyv/

Comment: @KingKongFrog: Personally I think I'd rather use a loop (`forEach`) to avoid having to copy the other properties. There's only one now, but if it expands later you don't have to worry about updating the `map` function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use: `myArray.map(..)`.

```
myArray = myArray.map(function(obj) {
    return {a: parseInt(obj.a), b: obj.b};
});
```

Or if you want to only modify property in-place:

```
myArray.forEach(function(obj) {
      obj.a = parseInt(obj.a);
});
//use myArray here; it has been modified above.
```

BTW, prefer the first version if you can. Personally, I like it when objects are immutable.

Comment: Also, it's almost always better to use `parseInt(string, 10)` (i.e. state your number base explicitly).

Comment: Looks fine, but it does create a new array with all new objects, it doesn't just change the values, if that's somehow important

Comment: @NikitaBaksalyar, Agreed. I hope OP heeds your comment.
Adeneo: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Standard loop:

```
for (i=0; i< myArray.length; i ++){
    myArray[i].a = parseInt(myArray[i].a,10)     
}
```

Comment: Although your second piece of code works, using functions that modify objects in place for `map` is a bad idea. Functions applied on an array of objects using map do not modify the objects. They return a brand new clone with appropriate changes. I'd suggest you use `forEach` instead of `map`. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28703680/227884).

Comment: @Thrustmaster removed the Map approach.